# skip a for-loop but from function which is called inside that loop in c#

Tags: c#

hey guys m running into a problem, i have a forloop n in that i call a function, and in that function i have a if condition, i want to skip 1 loop if condition gets true, for this problm i was thinkin' to use `goto` statement but as i read in many forums that `goto` statement is an evil... can it be solved without using `goto` statement, ne ideas i dn't want to use 'goto'

```
for(int i=0;i<gridview.rows.count-1;i++)
{
 //some operation;
 aFunction(param1,param2);
}

public void aFunction(param1,param2)
{
 //some operation;
if (!Regex.IsMatch(RechargeText, "successfully"))
        {
            RechargeStatus = "Failed";
            Program.sp.SoundLocation =
                System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) +
                "/aimlife_error.wav";
            Program.sp.Play();
        }
        else if (Regex.IsMatch(RechargeText, "Processing") || Regex.IsMatch(RechargeText, "Not"))
        {
            // here i need to skip the Loop
        }
        else
        {
            Program.sp.SoundLocation =
                System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) +
                "/aimlife_success.wav";
            Program.sp.Play();
        }
        Program.StatusMessage = "Recharge Successful";
        TextFill();
}
```

Actually there are some error list that are accepted errors, so i dn't need to update that in db, So my `TextFill();` function shud not run for accepted errors

**Snippet Edited**

Comment: no i can't test `abc` in forloop, it has sm purpose here

Comment: What's the usage of param1, param2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`goto` won't help you anyway. Basically you can't continue from a different method at all. The only simple way you can keep roughly your current flow is something like this:

```
bool shouldSkipNext = false;
for (int i = 0; i < gridview.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    if (shouldSkipNext)
    {
        shouldSkipNext = false;
        continue;
    }
    // some operation
    shouldSkipNext = aFunction(param1, param2);
}

public bool aFunction(param1,param2)
{
    if (abc)
    {
        return true;
    }
    // Other stuff
    return false;
}
```

Note that this will skip the entirety of the next iteration of the loop - which isn't the same as just `continue`. If you have more code *after* the call to `aFunction` and you want to skip *that* (which is the equivalent of `continue`) then it's simpler:

```
for (int i = 0; i < gridview.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    // some operation
    if (aFunction(param1, param2))
    {
        continue;
    }
    // Other stuff which will sometimes be skipped
}
```

Comment: hey i have some other stuff too after `aFunction`, n i dn't want to skip that one !

Answer (score 4):

Simple, have the method return a bool.  Then you can do:

```
for(int i=0;i<gridview.rows.count-1;i++)
{
    //some operation;
    if (aFunction(param1,param2)) break;
}
```

Comment: no !! it not gonna work, wait i guess i need to edit the snippet so that u' all can understand it completely

Answer (score 2):

All you want to do is skip executing the TextFill() function when the condition `if (Regex.IsMatch(RechargeText, "Processing") || Regex.IsMatch(RechargeText, "Not"))` is true, thats all right?

You can simply return at that if condition, which will work out as you want:

```
else if (Regex.IsMatch(RechargeText, "Processing") || Regex.IsMatch(RechargeText, "Not"))
    {
          return;
   } .... // rest of the code as it is
```

now when the above condition works out as `true` it will return to the for loop and go with the next iteration and so on...

Cheers

Comment: works for this piece of code but has a different behaviour in general: if you return here and there follows code in the loop it would still be executed while continue would skip the whole iteration.

Comment: thats correct, in case there are more code that needs to be skipped at the function call then further changes are needed. But if all that @FosterZ needs is to only skip the TextFill() then this would suffice.

Comment: yes, i have more code after that function `afunction()`...that shld not be skipped...

Comment: @FosterZ: If there are code after the afuntion() called which *_should not be skipped_*, then my solution is ideal. On the other hand if you *_want to skip_* code inside the for loop after afunction() call then @Jon-Skeet 's solution is best.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i=0;i<gridview.rows.count-1;i++)
{
 //some operation;
 if (!aFunction(param1,param2)) continue;
}

public bool aFunction(param1,param2)
{
 //some operation;
if (!Regex.IsMatch(RechargeText, "successfully"))
        {
            RechargeStatus = "Failed";
            Program.sp.SoundLocation =
                System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) +
                "/aimlife_error.wav";
            Program.sp.Play();
        }
        else if (Regex.IsMatch(RechargeText, "Processing") || Regex.IsMatch(RechargeText, "Not"))
        {
            Program.StatusMessage = "Recharge Successful";
            TextFill();
            return false;
            // here i need to skip the Loop
        }
        else
        {
            Program.sp.SoundLocation =
                System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) +
                "/aimlife_success.wav";
            Program.sp.Play();
        }
        Program.StatusMessage = "Recharge Successful";
        TextFill();

        return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your code as posted is exactly how it is, then you could simply return, as the loop has no other operations.

Comment: He says, "I want to do "continue"" here. That's not break.

Comment: @Oded: I don't see anything about breaking. I see a request to *continue*.

Answer (score 0):

No, it can not be solved with a `goto`... thankfully.

There is nothing that you can do inside the method that will change the control flow in the loop, you have to return something from the method and use that in the code of the loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < gridview.rows.count - 1; i++) {
  //some operation;
  if (aFunction(param1,param2)) {
    // do something more here
  }
}

public bool aFunction(param1,param2) {
  //some operation;
  if(abc) {
    //skip the current for-loop i.e i want to do "continue" here;
    return false;
  } else {
    //normal
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int param1 = 0, param2 = 0;
    getResult(param1, param2);
}

public static void getResult(Object param1, Object param2) {
    for (int i = 0; i < gridview.rows.count - 1; i++) {
        if (!Regex.IsMatch(RechargeText, "successfully")) {
            RechargeStatus = "Failed";
            Program.sp.SoundLocation = System.IO.Path
                    .GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly
                            .GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
                    + "/aimlife_error.wav";
            Program.sp.Play();
        } else if (Regex.IsMatch(RechargeText, "Processing")
                || Regex.IsMatch(RechargeText, "Not")) {
            // just skip here then
            continue;
        } else {
            Program.sp.SoundLocation = System.IO.Path
                    .GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly
                            .GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
                    + "/aimlife_success.wav";
            Program.sp.Play();
        }
        Program.StatusMessage = "Recharge Successful";
        TextFill();
    }
}
```

You should extract

```
Program.sp.SoundLocation = System.IO.Path
                    .GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly
                            .GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
                    + "/aimlife_success.wav";
            Program.sp.Play();
```

and

```
 RechargeStatus = "Failed";
            Program.sp.SoundLocation = System.IO.Path
                    .GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly
                            .GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
                    + "/aimlife_error.wav";
            Program.sp.Play();
```

into its own methods to make this code clearer, looks like a mess.